# Visual Studio TFVC Merge Lines Misaligned

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, tfvc

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC).  I am trying to merge changes from a parent branch into a child, but I am getting tons of conflicts that shouldn't exist.  The compare function works fine and shows a hand full of difference, but the merge tool is trying to shuffle the 2 sets of code together like a deck of cards.  It's so bad, I would feel safer making the change manually.

Is there a way to help the Merge Tool identify the comparable lines of code?

Answer (score 2):

You can try the external Compare amd Merge Tools, e.g  [WinMerge](http://Tools%20to%20Compare%20and%20Merge%20Code%20Better%20in%20TFS%20Source%20Control), [ExamDiffPro](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_examdiffpro.asp) or [Beyond Compare](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eGAyWvstKCI).

***For example:***

Using **Beyond Compare** as an External Merge Tool:

Go to **Tools** | **Options** | **Source Control** | **Visual Studio Team Foundation Server**, then click **Configure User Tools** and then **Add**. Enter the following:

```
Extension: *
Operation: Merge
Command: <Path to BCompare.exe>
Arguments: /merge %1 %3 %2 /o:%4 /dn1:%6 /dn2:%8 /dn3:%7 /dno:%9 /nh
```

Then it will invoke the external compare and merge tool when you click **Merge Changes in Merge Tool** to resolve the conflicts. And based on my test it can identify the comparable lines.

For ExamDiff, you can reference : [Using ExamDiff Pro as an External Diff Tool](http://www.prestosoft.com/edp_versioncontrol.asp)

[image]