# Which file comparison tool will work with VSTS?

Tags: compare, comparison, azure-devops

I've always been a heavy user of comparison tools like Beyond Compare, which can also be integrated with Visual Studio. We've recently migrated to VSTS and I find I am unable to replicate the Beyond Compare integration with VSTS, nor can I find any comparison tool that can serve that same purpose.

Anyone have any suggestions how I can use VSTS in conjunction with a comparison tool to compare files within my source repo and my local file system in particular?

Comment: How did you develop your projects? Don't you connect to the VSTS with dev client?

Answer (score 0):

No such an extension or tool in VSTS.

You can use VSTS to source control your files and manage the builds releases etc.

Generally we need a dev client connecting to VSTS to get the sources and develop locally. Then check-in the changes back to VSTS.

The most commonly used client is **Visual Studio**. So you can continue to use the VS to compare the files.

Please refer to [Compare folders and files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/compare-folders-files?view=vsts) for details.

You can reference [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47937841/7466674) in another thread to integrate the **Beyond Compare** or **ExamDiff Pro** with Visual Studio.