# TFS-equivalent of Visual SVN features

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2017, visualsvn

I've been a long-time Visual SVN user, but now have to use TFS (TFVC) at work.

Am still trying to find a workflow that works for me.

My question: **Does the VS2017's TFS plugin have the equivalent of the following Visual SVN functionalities?**

Or if not, what would the recommended alternatives be?

### 1. Icon overlay for solution folders?

The TFS VS plugin does not appear to show icon overlay for solution folders?

[image]

### 2. Highlight different/modified lines in gutter?

Highlights lines that have been modified locally (compared to server/repository).

[image]

#### 2.1 Navigation using keyboard shortcuts?

Navigating between differences (local copy vs server/repository copy) inside **Visual Studio 2017** (without leaving the VS text editor)

- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd>: next **difference** in local copy

  - `VisualSVN.NextDifference`
- <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>: previous **difference** in local copy

  - `VisualSVN.PreviousDifference`
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd>: revert **differences** at selection

  - `VisualSVN.RevertThisBlock`

Once again, by **differences**, I mean:

- the **local** (working/checked out) copy, compared to the **repository's** copy.
- **not** on-disk/saved/session copy

In both cases above, my current TFS workflow involves using a separate compare tool.

If I have to make edits, it's either in the compare tool (where I lose intellisense and code completion), or constantly switching back to the VS text editor.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that TFS is a tool that provides source code management (either with TFVC or Git), reporting, requirements management, project management... etc, but not for developing/editing the codes...

> 1. Icon overlay for solution folders?

By default there isn't such a feature for Team Explorer. This mainly depends on the Plugins/Extensions. And I cannot find an existing extension to achieve that.
You can try to write your own extension or modify based on the existing ones if possible. This article may helps: [Why am I not seeing the Icon Overlays in Shell Extensions TFS Power tools ?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/youhana/2012/01/09/why-am-i-not-seeing-the-icon-overlays-in-shell-extensions-tfs-power-tools/)

> 2. Highlight modified lines in gutter?

If you mean editing the online codes in TFS, then unfortunately no such a feature.
However you can check out the files in Visual Studio, then edit the files in VS. VS can highlight the changes as you mentioned.

> alt + ] and alt + [: navigate to next/previous modification

In VS code editor, by default you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (`View.NavigateBackward`) shortcut.

And  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> (`View.NavigateForward`) shortcut, or assign custom shortcuts for them.

> ctrl + alt + z: revert modifications in selection

In VS code editor, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>z</kbd> to undo, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>y</kbd> to redo.

For the comparison, you can use VS compare the files, you can also integrate other compare tools (e.g. `Beyond Compare` or `ExamDiff Pro`) into VS, reference my answer in another thread: [Visual Studio TFVC Merge Lines Misaligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47930168/visual-studio-tfvc-merge-lines-misaligned/47937841#47937841)

---

**UPDATE:**

If you mean pick/undo/redo the changes between local copy and remote repository copy, unfortunately no such built-in features in VS.

However you can integrate other compare tools such as `Beyond Compare` into VS, then you can edit the file within the compare tool.

> Using Beyond Compare as an External Diff Tool:
>
> Go to **Tools** | **Options** | **Source Control** | **Visual Studio
>   Team Foundation Server**, then click **Configure User Tools** and then
>   **Add**. Enter the following:
>
> - Extension: *
> - Operation: Compare
> - Command: `<Path to BCompare.exe>`
> - Arguments: %1 %2 /dn1:%6 /dn2:%7 /nh

e.g:

Copy the changed lines from repo file to local file, you can select `Next Section` and `Prev Section` navigating to Next and previous difference. Also you can use the shortcuts within the compare tool, e.g <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to copy select lines or current section to right pane.

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply Andy. I think you might've misunderstood my question on keyboard shortcuts (navigation/undo/redo against server/repository copy, not saved copy). I've updated my question, and would appreciate if you could confirm if the feature is/is not in Visual Studio's TFS source control plugin/Team Explorer. Thanks.

Comment: @jayars If you mean pick/undo/redo the changes between local copy and remote repository copy, unfortunately no such built-in features in VS. However you can integrate other compare tools such as `Beyond Compare` into VS, then you can edit the file within the compare tool. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Andy, that answered my questions